# How to call a View from a Stored Procedure in Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Im in the process of migrating an Access DB to Sql Server 2008 and right now Im converting these Access macros to store procedures. Most of the macos are calling queries so Ill need to convert the queries into views and then have the stored procedure call the views. What is the syntax to call the view?

Answer (score 5):

Same syntax as selecting data from a table:

```
SELECT *
FROM view
```